# how to iterate entire column and retrieve every wildcard match row in the column excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to filter some data from the main table and categorize it according to the user preference. here is sample of data and what I want to achieve?

**main table:**

[image: main table]

**Goal:**

I want iterate the "test" column and match any row with *apple & *touch and copy that entire row in another sheet. So, expecting the filtered table as shown below.

[image: Goal]

I did some search and arrived at this formula to begin with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A3:A11,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*touch*",A3:A11,1)),ROW(A3:A11),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

The result I got is as shown below

[image: result I got]

Two issues that I need help with:

1. the formula skips the 1st match and only populates starting from the 2nd match.
2. how do I narrow my search so the result match row that has both "apple" & "touch"?

Comment: FILTER function? https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function

Answer (score 0):

if you have Excel 365, you can use FILTER function.

Something like:
`=FILTER(A2:C11,(A2:A11 = "*apple*")*(A2:A11 = "*touch*"))`

Comment: I don't believe wildcards can be used in that way with the `FILTER` function.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is going to enable data filtering. This works in all version of excel.

Click on the header column that you want to filter on. Assuming that Test is in A1, you click A1.
From the ribbon under Start, go to Sort and Filter... and choose Filter.
A dropdown box appears in all cells on that row. Click the dropdown box in A1, select Text filters -> Contains... And enter the word you want it to contain.

After applying the filter, you get a filtered result. All filtered out rows will be hidden, not deleted. You can undo the filter and apply a new one and even add more filtering to this filter, optionally from another column.

If you are happy with the result, make a selection that spans all cells, copy it, and on a new worksheet, paste the data.

Comment: In addition, you can use [**Filter by using advanced criteria**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b) - fill in the three auxiliary vertical cells with the words `Test|apple|touch` and specify them as the criteria range. Here you can specify that the result should be placed on another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

`Jos Woolley` is correct about wildcards used as in `Máté Juhász`'s answer. But the can be used in the process:

```
=FILTER(A3:C11, IFERROR(  SEARCH("*apple*",A3:A11),  0) * IFERROR(  SEARCH("*touch*",A3:A11),  0))
```

His idea, of using `FILTER` was perfectly good. Just have to create the strings to multiply with an extra trick or two.

`SEARCH` will generate numbers and/or errors. Any number it produces must be >=1 due to its nature. Excel will interpret ANY non-zero numerical value as `TRUE` so all the "finds" will show up that way. `IFERROR` can replace the errors (for non-matching rows) with 0's for `FALSE` thereby giving `FILTER` its expected string of TRUE/FALSE values (or 1/0 values... either will be used).

Side note:  the reason your formula was failing was that it can only return a single value, not all of them. So it would never have worked. Also, mattering only to the writing of the Question, it does return the first one found, not skipping the first and returning the second one.

To make your formula work, you would need to adjust the last parameter in your `SMALL` function to an array constant or something that would produce one. But... how would you know how many items to ask it to return? Hmm... perhaps using a `COUNTIF` to count matches? It WILL use wildcards so you could do that, and it wouldn't be any kind of nightmare, but still, an added level of difficulty.

Of course, one could say `IFERROR(SEARCH())` is an added level of difficulty too. So... probably only matters for large data sets in which the size limits on the two internally created and used array constants each approach creates would dictate the better way. In that case, I don't believe Excel places any such limit on `COUNTIF` while it does on the array the formula above creates so for large data sets, more than perhaps 2,000 rows at most, your formula with the `COUNTIF` modification in `SMALL` would probably be better.